# How can I extract the IP addresses from .cap file?

Tags: wireshark, packet-capture

I have a `fwcapture.cap` file, which is used by Wireshark.

in it, there have many IP addresses source IPs and destination IPs.

How can I extract the unique IP addresses(no mater source or destination) as a list?

Comment: Do you want a list of unique IP addresses from both source and destination or a list containing one set of IP addresses per packet? If neither of the above, it would be helpful if you could include a couple entries of this desired list in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `tshark`, which already in Wireshark installation.

```
tshark -T json -e 'ip.src' -e 'ip.dst' -r filename.pcap  | grep '\.[0-9]' | sort -u
```